# 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' even though I explicitly told it not to run the function if array is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using React to display an array of images. The image URLS are being retrieved from a database so I'm expecting them not to be there immediately, once loaded they're being passed as props to this component.

To prevent this causing an error I used two short circuit operators to prevent the map running if the array is undefined, but the function is still running and returning Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Any ideas why? Sometimes it works when I refresh the page.

```
{
    images !== undefined && images.length > 1 &&
        <React.Fragment>
            <ImageCarouselBtnForward icon={ faChevronRight } onPointerDown={() => incrementer(images, activeImage, '+')}/>
            <ImageCarouselBtnBack icon={faChevronLeft} onPointerDown={() => incrementer(images, activeImage, '-')}/>
            <ImageCarouselSlideIndicatorGroup>
                    {
                        images !== undefined &&
                        images.map((e, idx) => (
                            <ImageCarouselSlideIndicator 
                                idx={idx} 
                                activeImage={activeImage} 
                                arrLength={images.length} 
                                onPointerDown={() => incrementer(images, activeImage, null, idx)}
                            />
                        ))
                    }
           </ImageCarouselSlideIndicatorGroup>
       </React.Fragment>
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This suggests that you're getting this error elsewhere, not in the code shown. (Much less likely: `undefined` has been shadowed.) Separately, rather than testing explicitly for `undefined`, I'd probably just use a truthy test: `images && images.length > 1 && ...` (and you don't need the other one).

Comment: Have you tried using a regularl `if condition`?

Comment: I'm wondering if `images?.map` would work. Would probably use != undefined though. Unless you initialize your array with [] in which case it would also need a length test

Answer (score 0):

Try images != undefined.

Or initialize images with []. and you do not have to put that undefined check. You just need images.length check.

Answer (score -1):

As a work around I moved the short circuit up to the parent element to prevent the entire component rendering until the image array is available.

To fix the original issue I initialised images as an empty array.

Comment: That's great and makes sense, but the code in the question will work if `images` is either an array or `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry If I'm being dense but can you explain this further? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm saying the guards you have in place in the question will work. If you're still getting the error, it's coming from other code, or an older copy of the code before you added them, etc. Adding the condition to the parent makes sense, but it doesn't solve the problem the question asks about, because the problem the question asks about doesn't occur with the code in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah I see what you mean, I think you're correct. Initialising images as an empty array as suggested by others seems to fix the issue.